# Why was the Sorcerer's Stone in Gringotts in the first place?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

The stone belonged to Nicolas Flamel who lived in Paris. Why did it have to be kept in Gringotts? Flamel had obviously kept the stone with him all along.

Comment: Presumably because there isn't a first class vault in Paris and because going to London (as a wizard) is trivially simple by Port-Key

Comment: "Nicholas Flamel meets Albus Dumbledore" is newsworthy ("and hands over a small stone-sized package", even more so).  "Nicholas Flamel visits Gringotts while in London" is significantly less so.  However, I suspect this will probably be entirely opinion-based...

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133071/76048). Flamel still had access to the Stone while it was in Gringotts.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Nicolas Flamel didn't live in Paris during the 1980s

Although Flamel is shown to have lived in Paris during the events of *Fantastic Beasts: Crimes of Grindelwald*, he didn't live in Paris anymore (at least not during the Harry Potter time). He lived in Devon county, in Southwest England.

> There have been many reports of the Sorcerer’s Stone over the centuries, but the only Stone currently in existence belongs to Mr. Nicolas Flamel, the noted alchemist and opera lover. **Mr. Flamel, who celebrated his six hundred and sixty-fifth birthday last year, enjoys a quiet life in Devon with his wife, Perenelle (six hundred and fifty-eight).**  
>    <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone: Chapter XIII: Nicolas Flamel*</sub>

### 2. Gringotts is the safest place in the world

When Hagrid goes to recover the "package" for Dumbledore, he tells Harry

> Yeah — so yeh’d be mad ter try an’ rob it, I’ll tell yeh that. Never mess with goblins, Harry. **Gringotts is the safest place in the world fer anything yeh want ter keep safe — ‘cept maybe Hogwarts**. As a matter o’ fact, I gotta visit Gringotts anyway. Fer Dumbledore. Hogwarts business.” Hagrid drew himself up proudly. 
>    <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone: Chapter V: Diagon Alley*</sub>